# Parsing information between known variables

Tags: php, regex

I dont mean to be a bother and I know this has been asked a thousand times before but i'm just not understanding the concept.  I was wondering if somebody could walk me through it, Here is what i'm trying to do:

I have a set of information inside an html file. The file is uploaded to the server and i need to parse information out of the file inside of set parameters (demo code to follow).  I have been reading on parsing for over a week and understand some of it but just not grasping the concept, i guess i just need somebody to do one on this demo for me to understand and if you could, break down the search variables please.  Here's the demo:

```
<hr>
<a id="Operating_System"></a>
<table WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER">
<CAPTION ALIGN="TOP"><FONT size="5">Operating System</FONT></CAPTION>
<tr><td><a href="#TOC">Top</a></td></tr>
<TR ALIGN="LEFT" BGCOLOR="#00FF00">
<TH>Property</TH>
<TH>Value</TH>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0">
<TD>Name</TD>
<TD>Windows 7 Professional x64 Service Pack 1</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Features</TD>
<TD>Terminal Services in Remote Admin Mode, 64 Bit Edition, Media Center Edition, Multiprocessor Free</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0">
<TD>Up Time</TD>
<TD>5 Days 22 Hours 4 Minutes 26 seconds</TD>
</TR>
<!-- Operating System Duration: 1.853 seconds -->
</table>
<hr>
<a id="Installed_Updates"></a>
<table WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER">
<CAPTION ALIGN="TOP"><FONT size="5">Installed Updates</FONT></CAPTION>
```

and here is what i'm trying to accomplish.  On this demo, i would need the information parsed but only certain information to come back.  there is a lot more information here but only need about 30 things total on each document. first i need to search from Operating_System to Installed_Updates, this will give me the first set area i need to gather information (there is other groups too so i'll make one for each group of information).  The i need to make the search more specific such as from `<TR>` to `</TR>` which will give me the actual information set i need.  After that just grap the first 'name' and 'value' to store in a database.

Again, i know it's out there but i'm just not getting the whole concept of simple expressions.  After i do it a few times on an actual document, i'll get the hang of it i think.

Thank you all so much for the help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by variables. If you want to extract table values, there are existing solutions: [html table parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+html+table+parser). If you don't know anything about regular expressions, you should not use them. phpQuery or QueryPath are easier for *\*parsing\** html.

Comment: by variables i mean the code elements, sorry.  They never change and in fact, the first text strings do not change either but these html pages' output is over 10 pages of content and i only need maybe 30 strings total on all pages (total 3 pages per user) that's why i was trying to do the regular expressions.  I have been looking into the table parsers as well but not sure if they will fit my needs by giving me all of the content and wasting resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works for fixed HTML with little variations. But if you just want a simple example, here is one:

```
preg_match('#<TD>Up Time</TD>.*?<TD>([\w ]+)</TD>#is', $html, $match);

print $match[1];                   # ^^^^^^
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for some tools. And http://regular-expressions.info/ to learn the syntax.

But as said, if you want to extract a lot of values, there are easier options.